# per group assign to every start time the latest end time and transport mode that belongs to the highest ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, missing-data, imputation

I have a data manipulation problem for which I can solve both imputation individually but not both simultaneously. I have a dataset of tracks which is grouped by `ID` (different persons), each track has a start time, end time, unique ID and sometimes a transport mode (but this can be missing). Lets just say that in the process of collecting the data some bugs occurred and that now many tracks have been saved multiple times (so tracks with different trip IDs, but the same person ID, start time and same end time, or tracks with the same person ID, start time and different end times or transport modes. I have figured out that the correct way of handeling this data is for a track with the same person ID and the exact same start time to save the latest end time and the travel mode belonging to highest trip ID. SO, it does happen that a trip with the same start time has different travel modes, and in that case I want to keep the travel mode belong to the highest trip ID (grouped by person ID and start time). However, this trip does not necessarily have the latest end time, and I do need to save per trip the latest end time in that group (person ID and start time). If for a certain trip there is no travel mode at all, this also needs to stay missing. Apologies for the fact that I cant describe this any clearer, hopefully the example explains what I am looking for:

## input

```
| ID_person | ID_Track | START | END | mode |
|-----------|----------|-------|-----|------|
| 1         | 1        | 8     | 10  | A    |
| 1         | 2        | 8     | 10  | NA   |
| 1         | 3        | 8     | 10  | B    |
| 1         | 4        | 8     | 11  | NA   |
| 1         | 5        | 8     | 10  | A    |
| 1         | 6        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 7        | 12    | 13  | NA   |
| 1         | 8        | 12    | 13  | A    |
| 1         | 9        | 14    | 15  | NA   |
| 2         | 10       | 8     | 9   | NA   |
| 2         | 11       | 8     | 9   | NA   |
| 2         | 12       | 8     | 11  | A    |
| 2         | 13       | 8     | 9   | D    |
| 2         | 14       | 8     | 10  | B    |
| 2         | 15       | 12    | 13  | D    |
| 2         | 16       | 15    | 16  | NA   |
```

## what I want

```
| ID_person | ID_Track | START | END | mode |
|-----------|----------|-------|-----|------|
| 1         | 1        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 2        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 3        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 4        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 5        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 6        | 8     | 11  | C    |
| 1         | 7        | 12    | 13  | A    |
| 1         | 8        | 12    | 13  | A    |
| 1         | 9        | 14    | 15  | NA   |
| 2         | 10       | 8     | 11  | B    |
| 2         | 11       | 8     | 11  | B    |
| 2         | 12       | 8     | 11  | B    |
| 2         | 13       | 8     | 11  | B    |
| 2         | 14       | 8     | 10  | B    |
| 2         | 15       | 12    | 13  | D    |
| 2         | 16       | 15    | 16  | NA   |
```

### some code to get the input

```
df <- structure(list(ID_person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                             1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ID_Track = 1:16, START = c(8L, 
                                                                                         8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 15L
                             ), END = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 9L, 9L, 
                                        11L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 16L), mode = c("A", NA, "B", NA, "A", "C", 
                                                                         NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "D", "B", "D", NA)), .Names = c("ID_person", 
                                                                                                                                    "ID_Track", "START", "END", "mode"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID_person, START) %>%
  mutate(
    END = max(END),
    mode = mode[which.max(ID_Track)]
  )
```